# The level of security regarding a TeamViewer host deployment

Tags: hardening, teamviewer

I'm a systems specialist in our organization and I've read a lot about TeamViewer security concerns over the last few years. Now I decided to come seek professional and objective opinions about the security of the following scenario:

- TeamViewer Corporate license
- TeamViewer account with a complex password and 2FA enabled
- Full TeamViewer client for admin to give remote assistance (random password disabled)
- TeamViewer custom host module with account assignment for the admin account (easy access/unattended access) enabled, so the deployment happens with the specific api token

On top of that there's a policy attached to the custom host module deployment that specifies the following things for every host:

- Install all new updates automatically, enforced
- Whitelist in use to allow connections only from the admin account, enforced
- Prevent the unassignment of the assigned admin account in host modules, enforced
- Any changes to host requires local admin password, enforced
- Random password disabled on host modules, enforced

Does this setup look like it's secure enough to let those host modules run on computers so that the admin can take unattended access whenever needed? If not, please include reasons for it and/or tips and tricks to make it more secure.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In general with services, in your case Team Viewer, that you have security concerns about it because they communicate over non-trusted networks such as Internet, the approach that I follow is basically to tunnel the service from source with SSH. On the server side the service is only accessible from a trusted network and is not exposed to the Internet. On the client size, the user just need to make a ssh tunnel and use all the security that ssh brings you, and the configure your service to use the exposed port by Team Viewer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm actually not so concerned over the connection itself because it seems TeamViewer has a quite good encryption in place for the remote connections (as said here https://www.teamviewer.com/en/trust-center/security/). I'm after a more specific opinions/information regarding the security in the scenario I've laid out in my quetsion. :)

Comment: So in that case probably with automatic updates, and 2FA should be ok. On the other hand, you can make an audit to the service and see if you have security  breaches